# How does the divergence change under a change of frame (with geometric algebra)?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, clifford-algebra

I'm trying to prove equations (85) and (86) from Hestenes' paper [*Gauge Theory Gravity with Geometric Calculus*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10701-005-5828-y) ([ResearchGate version](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226117395_Gauge_Theory_Gravity_with_Geometric_Calculus)).
$$
\dot{\nabla}^\prime \cdot \dot{\underline{f}}(A) = J_f^{-1}[ (\nabla \ln J_f) \cdot A ] = (\nabla^\prime \ln J_f) \cdot \underline{f}(A).
\tag{86}$$

I think we can say that
\begin{align}
 \quad \nabla^\prime \cdot A^\prime
&= \nabla^\prime \cdot \underline{f}(A) \\
&= \dot{\nabla}^\prime \cdot \underline{f}(\dot{A}) + \dot{\nabla}^\prime \cdot \dot{\underline{f}}(A)  \\
&= \underline{f}[ \bar{f}(\nabla^\prime) \cdot A ] + \dot{\underline{f}} [ \dot{\bar{f}}(\dot{\nabla}^\prime) \cdot A ] \\
&=\underline{f}[\nabla \cdot A] + ???
\end{align}

I used overdots to indicate what the derivative is acting on. I have no idea how to manipulate the gradient of natural log terms.

Seemingly,
$$
\nabla \ln J_f = J_f^{-1} \nabla J_f
$$

This attached page has more context. I don't understand how the equations between (84) and (85) relate to this (if at all).

[image]